# Why doesn't valgrind detect memory leaks?

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to figure out why `valgrind` doesn't detect any errors when I deliberately avoid freeing memory. I have this small program. It reads numbers from the keyboard and prints the message `You've entered <number>!`. If the number was previously read then it prints `You've already read <number>!`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int number;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* add(struct node* head, int number) {
    struct node* n;
    struct node* p;
    
    n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->number = number;
    n->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        return n;
    }

    p = head;
    while (p->next != NULL) {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = n;
    return head;
}

void clear(struct node* head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    clear(head->next);
    free(head);
}

int already_read(struct node* head, int number) {
    struct node* p;
    if (head == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    p = head;
    while (p!=NULL && p->number!=number) {
        p = p->next;
    }
    
    if (p == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int number;
    struct node* head = NULL;
    while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1) {
        if (already_read(head, number)) {
            printf("You've already entered %d!\n", number);
        }
        else {
            head = add(head, number);
            printf("You entered %d!\n", number);
        }
    }
    clear(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using gcc (This file is called `program.c` on my system, so I used the command `gcc -Wall -g -o program program.c`). It compiles fine. Then when I run it with valgrind (`valgrind ./program`), I enter some numbers to see that the program works and then I stop it with `CTRL-C`. I get no errors. Great.

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
    definetely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    still reachable: 64 bytes in 4 blocks
         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 context (suppressed: 8 from 6)
```

Then I go back in the code. I leave everything as it is, except I change the line in `main()` that reads `clear(head)` to `//clear(head)`. So now the program doesn't free the space anymore. It has leaks. I recompile and run it again with `valgrind`. I enter the same input as before. And... I get the same error report. Exactly the same as the one above. I don't understand why this is happening. Shouldn't it report memory leaks, since I didn't free the memory? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `clear(head);` occurs right before `return 0;` at which point all of the allocated memory is freed and returned to the operating system automatically.  That's probably why Valgrind didn't report a memory leak; *there isn't one.*

Comment: If you `Ctrl-C` when waiting for input then `clear()` never gets called, so whether it's there or not is irrelevant.  If it does get called (e.g. if you end the file with `Ctrl-D`) then it infinitely recurses and crashes.

Comment: And if `clear` isn't called then your memory is still reachable.  `valgrind` doesn't treat this as a leak; it assumes you needed that memory up to the end of the program and are relying on it to be automatically freed at exit.  If that's not your philosophy, then you can interpret the "still reachable" entry as leaks.

Comment: BTW, the code shown doesn't compile. It is missing a `p` declaration in `already_read`. Also the `clear` function doesn't make sense - it will cause a stack overflow and/or other undefined behaviour because it recursively calls itself infinitely with the same pointer value.

Comment: Following up on the last message, you need to copy and paste the **exact** code that you are compiling and running.  A retyped approximation isn't good enough.

Comment: @dbush My bad. Sorry.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for noticing that, I edited it. My bad, I retyped the code and made mistakes.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're right, that was the problem. I fixed that infinite recursion and used `CTRL+D` instead of `CTRL+C` and valgrind found the leaks. I didn't know these 2 commands work like this. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "at which point all of the allocated memory is freed and returned to the operating system automatically" -why is this exactly? Can you please explain, I don't think I fully understand what you're saying.

Comment: Calling `malloc` issues a request to the operating system for a block of memory, so the operating system knows about all of the memory that gets allocated and freed.  When the process exits, the operating system reclaims any memory blocks that have not yet been freed.

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Also, just invoke a *matching-failure* to stop input. E.g. just type an `'a'` (or any other non-digit aside from `+/-`) and the test for the `scanf()` return will fail breaking the read-loop. At that point all memory will be freed. Avoid recursion, `void clear (struct node *head) { while (head) { struct *node victim = head; head = head->next; free (victim); } }`

Answer (score 0):

If I run the code with the clear call commented out and enter 1, 2, 3, 2, q then I get

```
==60380== 48 (16 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==60380==    at 0x4839755: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==60380==    by 0x401178: add (test.c:14)
==60380==    by 0x401335: main (test.c:63)
==60380== 
==60380== LEAK SUMMARY:
==60380==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==60380==    indirectly lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==60380==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60380==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60380==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Command `valgrind --leak-check=full ./test`

This is exactly what I would expect. This is on amd64 so each node is 16 bytes. 3 nodes are allocated (for 1, 2 and 3 but not for the duplicate 2 or the q). At the end of `main()` the `head` variable goes out of scope. So at termination no pointers exist that point to the head (1) node -> it is a definite leak. Due to the linked list, pointers do exist to the (2) and (3) nodes (the pointer from the head node to (2) and from (2) to (3). Thus the (2) and (3) nodes are indirect leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you press `CTRL+C` you do not `exit()` your program, instead, you `SIGINT` your program. The difference is: The execution of your program ends abruptly, the `clear()` function will not be called and the function `main()` will also not return at all. `valgrind` will now see a program in a state, in which `main()` is still running, the life-time of local variable `head` has not ended yet and hence all memory referenced thereof is still reachable. As Paul Floyd already pointed out, when you quit your program by pressing `q`, the memory leak introduced by commenting out `clear(head);` will indeed show up. But for that you actually have to quit your program using `q` and not terminate it by `CTRL+C`.